# C++: when returning address of class member variable, compiler forces it to be const * type

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I was trying to write a convenience function to provide a pointer to an unordered_map which is buried inside of an object contained by another object.  For some reason the compiler (Visual Studio 2010) is forcing me to declare the pointer as a pointer to a const object.

The function code looks like this: (I didn't want it to have a `const` return type):

```
const ezx::iserver::strategy_map* strategy_map(const ezx::iserver::StrategyInfo* strategyInfo)
{
  if (strategyInfo)
  {
     const ezx::iserver::strategy_map* map = &strategyInfo->strategyTVS.tagValues;
     return map;
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

The object is defined without any const modifier:

```
class TagValueMsg : public EZXMsg
{
    public:     
      strategy_map tagValues;
      ...
}
```

This TagValueMsg is contained as a member field in another class.

```
class StrategyInfo : public EZXMsg
{
     public:
    TagValueMsg strategyTVS;
        ...
}
```

Since nothing is declared `const` anywhere, I don't understand why `const ezx::iserver::strategy_map*` is required?

Comment: The strategyInfo parameter is pointer to const

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your enclosing object is also `const` when passed into the function:

```
strategy_map(const ezx::iserver::StrategyInfo* strategyInfo)
```